# Joomla - calling the username with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, joomla

I am working on a simple game to add to my joomla site, done in html/javascript.  I want to be able to track user scores, I figure the easiest way to do that is to have the scores saved by username... but I can't figure out how to have joomla provide the javascript with the username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all of the information about the currently logged in user from the `JUser` object. To get it and store it in a variable named `$user`, use this code:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

From this object, you can get the username, id, email address, and other information about the user:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user->username ?>" id="username" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user->id ?>" id="id" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user->email ?>" id="email" />
```

Then you can call JavaScript to extract the information from HTML. Once you're ready to record the high score, you could make an AJAX-style call pointing to a Joomla component.